# Unable to install modules using 'pip' or 'easy_install' on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip

Default Python installation is 2.7.x on Mac. (currently running El Capitan)

I've changed default to 3.4.5.(mandatory for my course)

I was instructed by my professor to use MacPorts and it requires an SSL to download libraries so we are using following code to bypass it:

```
#from https://dnaeon.github.io/disable-python-ssl-verification/
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

#download all nltk data
nltk.download('all')
```

Everything installed using MacPorts works just fine, but most of the libraries are not available on MacPorts, so when I try to use pip3, it simply downloads the library but it never works. For exmaple:

In Terminal,
[image]

In Python Shell,
[image]

If I use 'pip' instead of 'pip3', it installs libraries for python 2.7.x.
I've tried the same process with tweepy and twython, but it doesn't work after installation. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing the following command:

```
$ sudo python3 -m pip install textblob
```

Best way would be to clone the repo:[EDIT]

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob.git
$ cd TextBlob/
$ python setup.py install
```

For more details see [this](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html)

Comment: The second method doesn't work for me. Just tried first method, works fine!

Comment: If you try the second command, you need to `cd` into the TextBlob folder before running setup.py.

Comment: That I know and I have tried the same way, but it just doesn't work, but it's okay since the first one is working.